# Set Oracle system parameter back to default

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

The parameter in question is `LOCAL_LISTENER`. Previously when running `SHOW PARAMETER LOCAL_LISTENER` no value was returned. Some time ago this was changed to some value. We are now having listener issues and want to get it back to default. Do I use the same `ALTER SYSTEM` command, but with a blank string or is there some other way?

Comment: The default, as [stated in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10820/initparams112.htm#REFRN10082), is `(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=hostname) (PORT=1521))`; can you just explicitly set it to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "`alter system reset ...`"